# What is the best way to write large xml file from mongodb document?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, mako

My task is basically simple. I want to make a query (which returns about 50k document) and with those results I want to write an xml document. I have a desired template on which I want my fields to put.

I have used Mako already, which is pretty pretty slow. So basically I am here for a fast alternative/approach.

My attempt is below:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from mako.template import Template
from mako.runtime import Context

temp = '''<jobs>
    % for i in data:
    <job>
         <city>${i['city']}</city>
         <created_at>${i['created_at']}</created_at>
         <description>
             ${i['description']}
         </description>
    </job>
    % endfor
</jobs>'''

client = MongoClient("")
result = client.db.col.find({'field': 'value'})

tpl = Template(temp)

with open('output.xml', 'w') as f:
    ctx = Context(f, data=result)
    tpl.render_context(ctx)
```